# How to attach item in one-to-many relation in ELoquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have model `Post` which could have many files. Info about files is stored in db with model `File`. So each `Post` can have many `File`, but every `File` have only one `Post`.

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    protected $table    = 'posts';
    protected $guarded  = array('id');

    public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('File', 'post_id', 'id');
    }
}

class File extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'files';

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

The problem is that the file is uploaded before post saved. When I save post I have an array of ids of files like `array(34, 35, 36);`. How to associate them with current post? `attach` and `sync` methods as far as I now works only with `many-to-many` relation.

Comment: @SameerShaikh 4. But I think i could use the code from 5 also as in near future project would be rewrote  on the 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there's `save()` / `saveMany()` but those want Eloquent models passed. What you can do though, is to just update it manually:

```
$post = new Post;
// ....
$post->save();
File::whereIn('id', [34, 35, 36])->update(['post_id' => $post->id]);
```

Or if you wanted to use the relationship method:

```
$files = File::whereIn('id', [34, 35, 36])->get();
$post->files()->saveMany($files);
```